# PHP template was not found

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to return a PHP view from the controller I keep getting the following error:

```
The template "AuthBundle::login.php" does not exist.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

The controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AuthBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/user")
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        return $this -> render('AuthBundle::login.php');
    }    

}
```

The dev config file:

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['php', 'twig']
```

And the view resides inside `AuthBundle/Resources/views/login.php`.

The stack trace shows that the error exists in:

```
at PhpEngine ->load ('AuthBundle::login.php') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/PhpEngine.php at line 72   -
     */
    public function render($name, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $storage = $this->load($name); // here
        $key = hash('sha256', serialize($storage));
        $this->current = $key;
        $this->parents[$key] = null;
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from the doc:

> Template Suffix
>
> Every template name also has two extensions that specify the format and engine for that template.

Thus, try to rename file to `login.html.php`